# htaccess URL rewriting

Tags: htaccess

I want to redirect a request look like

```
mydomain.com/abc/def
```

to

```
mydomain.com/abc/index.php?q=def
```

where `abc` is a fixed directory name and `def` can be any string.

How can I do this using `.htaccess`?

Comment: You say "redirect", but presumably you mean "internal rewrite"? You want `mydomain.com/abc/def` to remain in the address bar?

Answer (score 1):

In `.htaccess` put:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !id=
RewriteRule ^abc/(.+) /abc/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note that I included a check for the presence of the `id` query string parameter to prevent the url `http://mysite.com/abc/index.php?id=def` from being rewritten.